case vs if performance-wise in mysql query
In a query I have a calculated field that is based on several criterias to be matched at the same time.
IF progress = 0
    IF start<now() AND end>now() THEN "delay"
    IF start<now() AND end<now() THEN "overdue"
IF progress BETWEEN 0 AND 1
    IF start<now() THEN "advanced"
    IF end<now() THEN "overdue"
    IF end>now() AND end*progress>=now() THEN "in progress"
    IF end>now() AND end*progress<now() THEN "delayed"
IF progress=1 THEN "completed"

I am looking at how to set this set of conditions performance-wise. Should I change the outer IF (the one about the progress field) to a CASE?

BETWEEN is inclusive, so there's overlap between the conditions. CASE can only be used for mutually-exclusive conditions. So if you change this to CASE it won't be equivalent.

If performance is the primary consideration, then I would recommend define the generated column as a STORED column. Then the performance of the expression only affects when you insert/update the row, not when you read the calculated value. A virtual generated column evaluates the expression on every read. A stored column only evaluates the expression once, when you insert/update the row.

If you do want to test the relative performance of expressions, then try using MySQL's BENCHMARK() function.

@BillKarwin Doesn't the choice depend on whether you read or write  the relevant columns more often?

The value of the calculation will change based on the value of today’s date. So cannot be stored on insert/update only. What today is on time may be delay tomorrow

You can't use NOW() in a generated column expression anyway. You may have to use a view.

@Barmar, Yes you're right, but it's typical for reads to greatly outnumber writes.

Assuming you fix the overlap problem I mentioned above, CASE should generally be preferred because it stops testing conditions once one of the conditions has succeeded. Your code will check for progress=1 even if it has already found that progress=0.

Also, if staying with IF, use IF..ELSEIF..ELSE construct unless multiple conditions are going to be met

@BillKarwin I’m currently using a simplified version of these conditions and now works flawlessly. Why do you say I can’t?

Is this in a trigger, or are you defining it as a generated column? What is the result of SELECT VERSION(); ?

@BillKarwin I am using this as part of a normal select not of a trigger. And I am running mysql version 8.3.0

Okay, you can use NOW() in an expression. I made the mistake of assuming you were defining the expression as a generated column in a table. There are limitations of what functions you can use in generated column definitions.

The syntax you show in your question is not valid syntax for MySQL's IF() expression. Perhaps if you show a working query example.


I am looking at how to set this set of conditions performance-wise. Should I change the outer IF (the one about the progress field) to a CASE?

It doesn't matter. Any difference will be trivial. MySQL might even implement them exactly the same.
Since it's part of the select clause it only affects the already selected rows. The process of reading, filtering, and sorting rows is much, much more expensive. It's much more important to focus optimization efforts on those portions of your query: where, order by, join, group by, your indexes, and so on.

Note: end is a SQL reserved word; it's ambiguous whether you're referring to the column or ending a block and this can cause hard to debug errors. Consider using the *_at and *_on conventions for timestamps and dates respectively. start_at and end_at for timestamps, start_on and end_on for dates.

Short Answer:  The performance diff between IF and CASE is probably insignificant.
Long Answer:  Well, your code won't work as it stands, but let me guess at what you intended:
IF start<now() AND end>now() THEN "delay"
IF start<now() AND end<now() THEN "overdue"

Assume start is necessarily less than end, change to
IF (start<now()) THEN
    IF (end>now()) THEN "delay" ELSE IF (end<now()) THEN "overdue"

or
IF (start<now()) THEN
    CASE WHEN end>now() THEN "delay"
         WHEN end<now() THEN "overdue"
    END

end*progress is too kludgy for words.  Write out the IF or CASE, then simplify.
